# How to set .ssh/config so it can be used on different computers where my username are different?

Tags: ssh, dotfiles

```
Host foo
  HostName foo.com
  User specialuser
  IdentityFile /Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa

Host *
  User defaultuser
```

On most machines, my UNIX login user name is `XXX`. But on one particular machine, it is `YYY`, how to modify this above `.ssh/config` file so it can work on all machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `%u` escape sequence, which expands to the current user's username:

```
Host foo
HostName foo.com
User specialuser
IdentityFile /Users/%u/.ssh/id_rsa

Host *
User defaultuser
```

Read under the `IdentityFile` section in `man ssh_config` for other escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

A better more cross platform solution using the %d homedir token might be:

```
IdentityFile %d/.ssh/id_rsa
```

or even more simply

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```